# How do I convert a relative path to a fully qualified path in C# / .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, path, filesystems, relative-path

Let's say I have a file name defined as "..............\bin\prices.xls", is there a simple way to convert that to a fully qualified path (one that includes the Drive letter, colon and all folders to the file)?

Comment: you are marking the file as "Content" and then using ApplicationDeployment.DataDirectory when the app is deployed right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [Path.GetFullPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx):

> Returns the absolute path for the specified path string.
>
> The absolute path includes all information required to locate a file or directory on a system.

Comment: +1 One thing to note is that Path.GetFullPath() will return the full path whether or not the file exists. This can be useful, but it's something to watch out for in some cases.

Comment: I wish I could up vote your answer more than once. This has plagued our team for years!

Comment: It's worth noting this is not the absolute, fully qualified path; it does not resolve through symlinks or from drive letters to UNC paths.